# SQL Carryover from previous month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some data that I am trying to get some counts on.  There are dates for when the record was entered and when it was closed, if it has been closed yet.  I want to be able to get a count of how many records were still open from the previous month as of the first of the month.  Here is an example.  First table is the data, second table is the results I am looking for.  In the second table, ignore the parenthesis, they are just the IDs of the records that make up that count.

```
Position    DateEntered   DateClosed
    1        12/15/2017   12/20/2017
    11       12/20/2017    1/7/2018
    2        1/23/2018     2/3/2018
    3        1/24/2018  
    4        2/15/2018  
    5        2/20/2018     5/16/2018
    6        3/3/2018      3/15/2018
    7        3/23/2018     4/12/2018
    8        4/11/2018     5/10/2018
    9        4/12/2018     4/25/2018
    10       5/4/2018   

Year    Month      Carried Over
2018    January        1 (11)
2018    February       2 (2,3)
2018    March          3 (3,4,5)
2018    April          4 (3,4,5,7)
2018    May            4 (3,4,5,8)
2018    June           3 (3,4,10)
2018    July           3 (3,4,10)
2018    August         3 (3,4,10)
```

Is this possible, and if so, how?  Been racking my brain on this one for a few hours.

Comment: If I'm reading your expected results correctly, you want the number of `Position`s that were marked `DateClosed` in that month, and in the parenthesis, the `Position` ids of the ones that closed but were open in a previous month. Correct?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: @Shawn . . . You are not reading the question correctly.  The OP only wants the number, not the list in parentheses.  I also think you are missing the definition of "carried over", so you might want to read the question more carefully.

Comment: Sorry, missed "ignore the parentesis". I was working out how to include the `Positions`. Doh!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each month, you want the number of rows that start before that month and end after.  I'm thinking:

```
with dates as (
      select cast('2018-01-01' as date) as dte
      union all
      select dateadd(month, 1, dte)
      from dates
      where dte < '2018-08-01'
    )
select d.dte,
       (select count(*)
        from t
        where t.dateentered < d.dte and
              (t.dateclosed > d.dte or t.dateClosed is null)
       ) as carriedover
from dates d;
```

Note that this puts the date in a single column, rather than splitting the year and month into separate columns.  That is easily arranged, but I prefer to keep date components together.

Comment: Is there a reason for an uncommented downvote, on what looks like a very reasonable answer to the question.

Comment: @dk96m If you need other dates, I might would recommend a Calendar Table for an issue like this. Then join to the Calendar Table with a filtered range instead of the recursive cte. The `dates` aren't really the important part of the query so much as Gordon's second part.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, this works great.  Assuming 2018, but what about if i have several years of data, how do i deal with that?

Comment: @Shawn Can you provide an example.  Ive never used a calendar table

Comment: Actually, I do have access to a calendar table now that I have looked it up.  How do I make that work with Gordans query?

Comment: Ok, I got it.  Thank you all.  I did use @GordonLinoffs query, with some edits.  I dont know how to post the code in the comments, but it is pretty much just that query.

Comment: My only issue now is, I cant use a CTE in a complex query like joins, etc